# Get locations nearby request.location with ruby/rails geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How would you get locations that are nearby your current location with geocoder gem for ruby on rails 3.2.x?

I know that to find locations near one of your other locations you would use

```
@myClass.nearbys(50)
```

but I would like them nearby the browsers location (request.location) instead of nearby another one of my locations.

Such that it would be similar to

```
request.location.nearby(50)
```

or something to that effect.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the longitude and latitude of the user's location, you can make a query like so

```
location_info = request.location

@locations = Location.near([location_info.latitude, location_info.longitude], radius_distance_you_want_to_include)
```

It would also be expected that your table, i.e. in the above example `Location` there should be `lat` and `lon` fields.

Is this something you were looking for?

EDIT: I'm not sure if `request.location` will work in the model. In case it doesn't, you can always set it as a parameter into a model method inside your controller so that your logic stays separated. But if you can, keep `request.location` in the model.

Comment: Yes, if I can find out how to get longitude/latitude from request.location.

Comment: Ahh so that's what you want. Ok let me look into that then.

Comment: I think it is just request.location.longitude, and request.location.latitude, but trying to test that.

Comment: That should do it. Those attributes do exist for `request.location`. What you can do is run `request.location.inspect` to see what's exactly being returned on your test environment. However, be aware that some user's may deny websites access to their geo coordinates. Updated my answer with the latest code as well.

Comment: Yes thanks this helped.  I also had issues due to my local development IP address actually being 127.0.0.1 but should be able to get around that with something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115589/geocoder-how-to-test-locally-when-ip-is-127-0-0-1

Comment: this solution for overriding IP during testing seemed simplest. http://blog.corykaufman.com/2012/09/11/geocode-localhost.html