# Get location co-ordinate In ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've heard of [Geocoder](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder/1.2.12) and [Geokit](https://rubygems.org/gems/geokit) but what I know is that they only work if we provide their functions some parameters . either city /country name or location co-ordinates . But what i want is to get my own location either `'Area name'` or `latitude` or `longitude` in ruby on rails ,with any gem . Don't suggest request.location because it give me localhost address , not my internet ip .so plz suggest anything reasonable because i'm totally freaked out

Comment: You cannot test it in local without passing some fake IP address, please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17034967/3863146), and there's one more thing, you can only make some limited number of requests for getting user location after that you will start getting error messages. You can also catch this exception but in the end only limited requests are allowed.

Comment: thanks sahil i think 127.0.0.1 will continue until we're at local , so we have to provide ip as mention in that answer

Comment: Checkout [this](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#google-google) while choosing which service you want to use for determining location.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ip using

```
ip = request.remote_ip
```

or

```
ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

or if you are using `devise` for user authentication you can just search by the ip obtained via `devise`

```
ip = user.last_sign_in_ip || user.current_sign_in_ip
```

Use `Geocoder`'s `search` method to get location and coordinates.

```
location = Geocoder.search(ip)
country = location["country_name"]
state = location["region_name"]
city = location["city"]
zipcode = geoloc["zipcode"]
latitude = geoloc["latitude"]
longitude = geoloc["longitude"]
area_code = geoloc["area_code"]
```

Comment: why devise to get IP?

Comment: I am just i inquiring if he's already using `devise` but if not just get the ip this way `request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'] `

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
location = IpGeocoder.geocode(request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

here is the [documentation](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) for the same

Comment: but for that thing we need the ip of the user , which we don't have and at this time `request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']` show us the `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi it happens on when you work with local, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115589/geocoder-how-to-test-locally-when-ip-is-127-0-0-1?lq=1

Comment: I hate it ;(  - but i found a solution which i'll explain later